# Firefox and Google Chrome css not the same?

Tags: html, css

When I test this

http://www.andrewsellick.com/examples/sliding-side-bar/#

results are buggy and not the same.

Don't both based on the same standard ?

Comment: You misspelled "padding" as "paddign", making your CSS invalid and causing that property be ignored.  However, that is probably unrelated to the discrepancy.

Comment: "Don't both based on the same standard ?" - technically yes, but they both get it wrong in different ways. Also, you should go back to your old questions and make sure you've marked good answers as accepted answers, since you seem to have a whole bunch of questions you're completely ignoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every browser has it's own default styles.

You should un-apply the browser defaults with a "reset" stylesheet (here is mine):

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
fieldset,img {
    border:0;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var {
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}

ul                              { list-style-type: none; }
ol                              { list-style-type: decimal; }

caption,th {
    text-align:left;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
q:before,q:after {
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym { border:0;
}


html, body                      { line-height: 1; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after         { content: ''; }
blockquote, q                   { quotes: "" ""; }


*                               { font-family: Verdana, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
                                  font-size: 13px; color: #666;
                                  text-decoration: none; white-space: normal;
                                  vertical-align: baseline; }

input[text="submit"], button    { color: #000; }
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML and CSS are rendered by each browser how they think it is better, based on some conditions. This can be done without violating the standard.

Think about it like two people reading a common text: their voices differ even if they both are reading it correctly.

That said, if you told us more in detail what you would expect to see, we would be able to actually help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use YUI to reset default browser css: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

That said, even resetters don't always work, but you can try them out. They'll certainly ease the pain to some degree.